# DVD Drive detects certain disks but not others

Tags: dvd, optical-drive

I have a Sony DVD RW DRU-V200S ATA Device; certain disks work fine with it, but it will refuse to run others.

I've done a couple of tests with different disks. It seems to work with audio CDs and old games that are on a CD rather than a DVD. It also works with DVD movies and some more modern games that are on DVDs; however not other games that are on DVDs. For example, it will run Rome Total War but not Medieval II Total War.

In explorer, it says DVD RW Drive (D:), but underneath that it says that it's a CD Drive. I'm using Windows 7.

When I insert the disk, it seems to start spinning it to the required speed, but then slows down, makes a noise and repeats.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If your DVD drive in Warranty then go to service center and checked it out otherwise its time to buy new one. In my case the same thing happen on laptop sometime it recognize the old DVD with scratch and not read the new one. And after sometime it completely worked off.

You can also try to clean the lance with very soft cotton and take a try.